# If statment to only show one value from an array

Tags: php, magento

I am using onestepcheckout in Magento. I have added in some extra flat rates and I am using two of them. I want to be able to only show one of the flat rates depending on the subtotal of the cart.

I have got the subtotal into a variable but the code has a foreach through each shipping method available so I need a way to say if `$total` is over 500 only show the second shipping method, if the total is under 500 only show the first shipping method.

```
<?php $total = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
                <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                            <dd><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dd>
                        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <dt style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?></li></ul></li></ul>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> />
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><!--<b><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?>:</b>--> <?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                                    <strong>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </strong>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </dt>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what part, specifically are you having trouble with? it looks like you know how to use `if` statements already.

Comment: @sgroves I need a way to get the two different rate `flatrate` and `flatrate2` into the if statment

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you show flatrate or flatrate2 anywhere, are they methods? or variables? or what?

Answer (score 0):

Just do ...

```
//first method here by default
if($total>500){
 //second method here
}
```

Something tells me you already know how to do this though

I can't decipher, what the first and second method are in your code, otherwise I would've posted a more complete code

Comment: It is using onestepcheckout the ajax part is seperate. The first method is `flatrate` the second method is `flatrate2`

Comment: Well without seeing any code, I would assume you have to do the same thing in the ajax side....declare a total...or at least pass this total into the ajax call, and accomodate on the other side

Comment: i think the problem is that he's using a third-party checkout system and can't edit the server side stuff. maybe. really hard to tell what he's trying to do at all